# How to switch between streams of data in Python Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I have two streams of data, both a series of (timestamp, value) tuples.
ie:

```
[(2013-04-03T22:16:36+0000, 2334.5), (2013-04-03T22:46:36+0000, 43543.23), ...]
```

The idea is one of these will be 'preferred' and one not, and I want to create a single time series that is a result of the higher preference stream when available, and falls back to a least preferable stream when not.

My idea was to put the timestamps of values from both streams into buckets, and use the buckets as an index for a DataFrame, with a column for each stream, and a list of (timestamp, value) tuples in each bucket. Then I can just go through per bucket, and choose the one with the highest number of points for example.

The data frame would look something like this:

```
timestamp            stream1                                  stream2  
2013-04-03 00:00:00  [(2013-04-03T00:16:36+0000, 2334.5),     [(2013-04-03T00:17:36+0000, 2314.5)]
                      (2013-04-03T00:17:36+0000, 2314.5)]
2013-04-03 00:30:00  [(2013-04-03T00:43:44+0000, 43543.23),   [(2013-04-03T00:47:36+0000, 2364.5)] 
                      (2013-04-03T00:54:24+0000, 4443.23)]
2013-04-03 01:00:00  []                                       [(2013-04-03T01:01:30+0000, 34.34)]
2013-04-03 01:30:00  [(2013-04-03T01:35:32+0000, 238734.3)]   [(2013-04-03T01:45:32+0000, 238734.3)]
```

In this situation, the timestamps have been put into half-hourly buckets, and stream1 is the preferred stream. For the bucket at 00:00, the two points in stream1 would be chosen, for the bucket at 00:30 the two points in stream 1 would be chosen, for the bucket at 01:00 the single point in stream2 would be chosen as stream1 has no data, for the bucket at 01:30 the single data point in stream1 would be chosen as it is the preferred stream.

How would I go about doing this? I have attempted creating the data frame and using `resample('h', how='count')` to split into hourly counts, and using `groupby`, but can't quite put the timestamps into buckets and create the lists of values for each stream per bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution but I'm not sure how efficient it is (being a Pandas noob myself), or if there is a way that is more 'panda-style':

```
hh = date_range('2013-01-01T00:30:00', periods=48, freq='1800S')
s5 = date_range('2013-01-01', freq='5S', end='2013-01-02')
s5 = s5[:720] + s5[1440:]  # introduce a gap in the 5 second data
hh_d = Series(hh.astype('int') / 10 ** 9, index=hh)
s5_d = Series(s5.astype('int') / 10 ** 9, index=s5)
df = DataFrame({
    'hh': hh_d,
    '5s': s5_d,
})
# Make a grouping, for simplicity by day, hour
grp = df.groupby(lambda x: (x.day, x.hour))

result = TimeSeries()
for name, group in grp:
    winner = None
    for column in group.keys():  # iterate over the columns (streams)
        data = group[column].dropna()  # ditch any NaNs that will be present
        # next, perform the test (in this case, just the length)
        if not winner or len(data) > len(group[winner].dropna()):
            winner = column
    # finally, add the data to the result set.
    result = result.append(group[winner].dropna())
```

Checking the result at the time of the 5 second gap gives:

```
ipdb> result[719:725]
2013-01-01 00:59:55    1357001995
2013-01-01 01:00:00    1357002000
2013-01-01 01:30:00    1357003800
2013-01-01 02:00:00    1357005600
2013-01-01 02:00:05    1357005605
2013-01-01 02:00:10    1357005610
dtype: float64
```

Which shows that the half-hour stream was selected during the gap.

The example above is based on length of each column in the group, but I guess any test could be applied.

Hopefully someone with more pandas experience can elaborate on my strawman answer!